# use a list to filter a file with multiple columns using awk/while?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm probably doing something silly here (new to awk)...

I have a BigFile with multiple columns which I want to filter the lines by a list of names (NamesList). These names are contained in the 4th column of the file.

trying to use a while loop

```
while read -r line; do 
cat BigFile.txt | awk '{if ($4=="$line") print $0;}' >> Output.txt
done < NamesList.txt
```

To print the filtered lines to Output.txt. This gives me a blank file :(

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: my lines don't work. edited the question

Comment: please post a testable fragments from both files

Comment: This technique (bash loop to read a line from the small file then process the big file using that line) will be extremely slow. You want a tool where you can process the small file first, remember the things to need to remember, then process the big file just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your implementation is that `"$line"` won't be expanded by the shell, since it's inside the single quotes enclosing your awk expression.

You *could* pass `$line` into awk as follows:

```
cat BigFile.txt | awk -v line="$line" '{if ($4==line) print $0;}' >> Output.txt
```

(note that this is a [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)). However unless you specifically need the matches in the order that would be produced by your loop implementation, it's probably better to skip the whole shell loop by having awk process both files directly ex.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} $4 in a' NamesList.txt BigFile.txt > Output.txt
```

(I'm assuming you only used `>>` because of the shell loop).